# Condition on a Fontaine Laffaille module which prescribes the image of the associated Galois representation

Tags: nt.number-theory, galois-representations, p-adic-hodge-theory

The Setup:

Let $m\geq 1$ be an integer, $\mathbb{F}$ be a finite field of characteristic $p$ and $W(\mathbb{F})$ the ring of Witt-vectors with residue field $\mathbb{F}$ and $\sigma:W(\mathbb{F})\xrightarrow{\sim} W(\mathbb{F})$ a lift of the Frobenius $\bar{\sigma}:\mathbb{F}\xrightarrow{\sim}\mathbb{F}$. 
Recall that filtered Dieudonne' $W(\mathbb{F})$-module also known as a Fontaine-Laffaille module is a $W(\mathbb{F})$-module furnished with a decreasing, exhaustive, separated filtration of submodules $\{F^i M\}$ and for each integer $i$ a $\sigma$-semilinear map $\varphi^i=\varphi_M^i:F^i M\rightarrow M$. These maps are required to satisfy two conditions

1. the following compatibility relation is satisfied $\varphi^{i+1}=p \varphi^i$,
2. $\sum_i \varphi^i(F^i M)=M$.

Let $\text{MF}_{tor}^{f}$ denote the category of Fontaine-Laffaille modules $M$ with morphisms satisfying the conditions alluded to above. For $a<b$ let $\text{MF}_{tor}^{f,[a,b]}$ let the full subcategory of $\text{MF}_{tor}^{f}$ whose underlying modules $M$ satisfy $F^0 M=M$ and $F^p M=0$.

The Fontaine-Laffaille functor $\text{U}:\text{MF}_{tor}^{f,[0,p]}\rightarrow \text{Rep}_{W(\mathbb{F})}(\text{G}_{\mathbb{Q}_p})$
where $\text{Rep}_{W(\mathbb{F})}(\text{G}_{\mathbb{Q}_p})$ is the category of continuous $W(\mathbb{F})[\text{G}_{\mathbb{Q}_p}]$ modules that are finite-length $W(\mathbb{F})$-modules. It is a basic fact that if $M$ has the structure of a free $W(\mathbb{F})/p^m$-module of rank $n$ (in greater detail, $F^j M$ are all free $W(\mathbb{F})/p^m$-modules and the maps $\varphi^j$ and semilinear $W(\mathbb{F})$-module maps) then $\rho_M:=\text{U}(M)$ is a Galois representation $\rho_M:\text{G}_{\mathbb{Q}_p}\rightarrow \text{GL}_n(W(\mathbb{F})/p^m)$.

**Question: Let $G\subset \text{GL}_n$ be an algebraic subgroup of $\text{GL}_n$ defined over $\mathbb{Q}$ (I'm mainly interested in the exceptional groups, like for instance $G_2$). What condition on the maps $\varphi^j_M$ ensures that the image of $\rho_M:=\text{U}(M)$ lies in $G(W(\mathbb{F})/p^m)$ so that it is a Galois representation $\rho_M:\text{G}_{\mathbb{Q}_p}\rightarrow G(W(\mathbb{F})/p^m )$.**

**Comment: For the classical groups like $\text{GSp}_{2n}$ this is done in section 2 of the paper of Clozel, Harris and Taylor "Automorphy of some $l$-adic lifts of Automorphic Mod $l$ Galois Representations". It involves making use of the alternating form and the functoriality of $U$.**

Comment: One approach would be to "cut out" the group $G$ by tensors inside $GL_n(V)$. That is, to find several elements in the tensor algebra $T(V)$ of $V$(or rather in the tensor product of tensor algebras of $V$ and $V^*$) such that $G$ is the stabilizer of these elements(an example of such tensor is an alternating form for $Sp_n$, as you said). Then a representation $\rho:G_{\mathbb{Q}_p}\to GL_n(V)$ factors through $G$ iff the map from a trivial representation to $T(V)$ which sends a basis into the tensors we picked is a morphism of representations.

Comment: Using that the functor $U$ is monoidal(which follows almost formally from its faithfulness) this translates into the condition that a certain subspace $W\subset T(U(\rho))$ is contained in the 0th piece of the filtration and $\varphi^0|_W=id|_W$. However, I don't yet see how to provide these tensors for a group over $W_m$, but for the cases $m=1,\infty$ this is definitely known. Here http://www.ams.org/journals/jams/2010-23-04/S0894-0347-10-00667-3/S0894-0347-10-00667-3.pdf Kisin does something similar with Breuil-Kisin modules instead of Fontaine-Laffaile modules.

Comment: @ SashaP, yes this is exactly what I was looking for, thank so you much! I am interested in the case when $m=\infty$. I would be happy to accept your answer.

Comment: Then I guess you could repeat verbatim what Kisin does. Though I should remark that this all applies only if you start with a representation which is admissible for the Fontaine-Laffaile functor.